# « (Faire de) l'esprit en bouteille », est-ce réellement une expression du français ?

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, origine-ou-raison

Je me souviens maintenant d'une expression que l'une de mes connaissances utilisait en parlant de l'humour douteux de certaines personnes dont elle disait qu'elles faisaient de l'esprit en bouteille (rien à voir avec le conte de Grimm, il me semble).

Je ne trouve aucune trace de cette expression et ne suis même pas sûr qu'elle soit utilisée autrement que localement ; elle ne laisse de traces ni dans les dictionnaires ni sur le Web.

Ce qui est sûr c'est qu'il ne s'agit pas de ce que les anglais appellent « chamber pot humour ». (Quel serait un équivalent français pour ce type particulier d'humour ?)

Est-ce que quelqu'un saurait si « faire de l'esprit en bouteille » est connu et si oui, la signification exacte, en donnant si possible des exemples d'esprit en bouteille ?

Comment: Décidément... Plutarque ne vous quitte plus. Jusque dans votre cave! *"de l'esprit en volume et du génie en bouteille!... Tonnerre! Ça mérite d'être répandu!"*

Comment: Quelle en serait l'origine, l'explication ? La référence à un contenant me faisait aussi penser à 'canned joke', mais le sens semble différent.

Comment: Comme Québecois je peut dire que j'ai entendue souvent Faire de l'esprit de bottinne, mais pas de bouteille par contre, donc je ne c'est pas si c'est un dérivé de la même expression.

Comment: Absolument rien dans Google Livres.

Answer (score 1):

"L'esprit en bouteille" se réfère aux spiritueux (et plus largement à l'alcool). Je ne suis donc pas sûr de ce que son expression voulait dire. Mais je sais que l'une des nombreuses blagues douteuses consistait à dire à un nigaud d'aller chercher de l'esprit en bouteille (jouant sur le double sens d'esprit : un alcool distillé, et l'intelligence). Un peu comme on demandait à la bleusaille de ramener la clef des champs de tir.

Comment: Il pourrait  y avoir une connexion.